# PuTTY: inputting some special characters doesn't work (Romanian)

Tags: linux, character-encoding, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to a CentOS server, and I sometimes need to enter Romanian characters from the keyboard. I use Windows 7 on the client computer; I have the server locale set up as en_US.UTF-8, and PuTTY is also configured for UTF-8.

I do NOT have any issues entering characters "î" and "ă" from the keyboard, and I also wouldn't have any problems entering the legacy cedilla characters "ş" (U+015F) and "ţ" (U+0163).

However, I can't enter the proper (comma) counterparts of the cedilla legacy characters "ș" (U+0219) and "ț" (U+021B). Whenever I try to use these two from the keyboard I get a question mark in the console. The issue is not related to the font I'm using in PuTTY, because I can copy/paste them (e.g. from this post), and I can generate them on the Linux host, e.g. by using

```
$ perl -Mcharnames=:full -CS -wle 'print "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW}"'
```

I use Microsoft's stock keyboard settings for Romanian -- both "Romanian (Standard)" and "Romanian (Programmers)" produce the same results; "Romanian (Legacy)" works properly, but produces the legacy cedilla variants, which I'd rather not use.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you perhaps using screen? If so you also need to configure screen to use UTF-8

Comment: Nope, just plain stock bash.

Comment: In my environment `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` not LOCALE, but I don't know if that makes a difference for you.

Comment: Yep, same here, I just didn't want to list all output from `locale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long history* this bug has been fixed in release 0.63
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist//win-tounicodeex.html

---

- As far as I know a Romanian programmer has patched putty 0.61 (and the svn of that time).
  Binaries and a breaindead-simple patch are available from this url: http://www.tehnica.org/putty/
  Found via https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/diacritice/I5tgcV7bE0M as the first result of search with keywords "[secarica](http://www.secarica.ro/) putty"

Comment: Oh, if it's a bug in putty then it's a bug in putty, and that's that. I thought I was doing something wrong (I thought I just had to fiddle with some locale settings somewhere).